# Jira/JQL filter for issues that haven't changed status within last X working days

Tags: jira, jql

I'd like to find all issues that haven't changed their status with eg 2 working days. I would be ok with ignoring bank holidays but would like to ignore weekends. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jira out of the box doesn't have the facility to ignore vacation days in JQL

[JRASERVER-22506 - JQL search with working days range](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-22506)

This thread might be helpful

[How do I create a JQL query which uses dates but allows for non-working days?](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-do-I-create-a-JQL-query-which-uses-dates-but-allows-for-non/qaq-p/367859)